# Custom Splash Screen - Android

Tags: android, animation, imageview

Currently my android application shows a black screen with a loading wheel as it processes the user's request i:e as it gets content from the server. I would like to modify this screen to include an icon (image) that fades in and out continuously instead of the loading wheel. Is there any possible way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll use an Alpha Animation

[See here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

[and here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html)

[and lastly here for a good tutorial on Animations with some nice code.](http://www.hascode.com/2010/09/playing-around-with-the-android-animation-framework/)

In order to "chain" your animations so that one starts after the other you'll use an Animation listener and start the other one from the onAnimationEnd method callback. Don't forget to put an if statement in there that checks to see if your stuff is done loading otherwise you'll end up with infinite recursion of your fade in and fade out.

Comment: Tim - Your tip about the onAnimationEnd method worked like a charm. Thanks again!