# How can I set animation for splash in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want to set animation for splash screen same as fade or slide some picture 
how can i do this for android project?

Comment: you may show your effort or at least some ideas first.

Comment: ok thanks for your response                                               Animate a "ANDROID" in middle of splash screen ;come word from left or right and complete in middle of page

Answer (score 3):

This is an excellent example with source code for Specific splash page:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113831/An-Advanced-Splash-Screen-for-Android-App

Custom Splash Screen:
[Custom Splash Screen - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573568/custom-splash-screen-android)

Answer (score 2):

Check out link below 
http://docs.xamarin.com/android/recipes/Other_UX/Animation/Frame_Animation

You have to use Animation in android. no difference to use java or mono

Comment: thanks I check that and it's work perfect but do you have another method for do this?

Comment: animation class is the best way to use animation effect in android

Comment: do you have sample code or did you do this with animation class?

Comment: Open this link below:
http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/rotating-text-animation/

Answer (score 1):

Create anim folder in res, in that create an xml file Example: fade_in_anim.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<alpha
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

In java declare animation

```
Animation _startAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in_anim);
```

Declare the view which wants to be animated

```
view.startAnimation(_startAnimation);
```

Comment: this way made animation splash screen completely and fade that but I want to animate just a word "ANDROID" in middle of screen same as scroll from left or right, have you plan for this?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

</set>

Answer (score 1):

You can load image in Webview.

First put your .gif image in Assets folder of your project and change its 
**Build Action=>AndroidAssest**.

Now assign your html code to string object.

```
string myhtmldata = "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
<body bgcolor='#000000'><img src='image_name.gif' width=100%></body></html>";
```

Pass this string object with Base URL in Webview.

```
webview.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", myhtmldata, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

It will display GIF image in Splash screen. !!